# Storing Ping.time in a float (Unity 2018)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ping, game-development, latency

Anyone knows any method on how i can store the Ping in a float value so later i can display it in a chart. Currently with the below code, **Pinging** is only displaying -1 while in the text the correct ping is showing. Thanks

**Ping Code**

```
IEnumerator TestPing()
{
    var PingTest = new Ping("http://localhost:8081/website/index.php");
    pinging = PingTest.time;

    while (!PingTest.isDone)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);

    pingText.text = (PingTest.time).ToString() + " ms";
}
```

Comment: Can't you just parse it as a float? `float myIncredibleFloatValue = float.Parse(myPingValue);`

Comment: Does not work like this :  float pinging = float.Parse(PingTest.time);

Comment: As Onikur says, if youre waiting the ping to complete, the pinging should be after the while. Thats why the text shows a correct value

Comment: Also note that [`Ping`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ping-ctor.html) states `This does not perform DNS lookups on host names so it only accepts IP addresses in dot notation.` so while this works on localhost where no DNS lookup is required it will always fail if your goal is later to ping the page from another device except you feed it the IP address instead.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you may want to get the ping time after `isDone`?

```
IEnumerator TestPing()
{
    var PingTest = new Ping("http://localhost:8081/website/index.php");

    while (!PingTest.isDone)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);

    pinging = PingTest.time;
    pingText.text = pinging + " ms";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PingTest.time` is an `int` - a value type. And `pinging` is a `float` - also a value type.  That means, when you assign `pinging = PingTest.time`, you are assigning the current value of `PingTest.time` to `pinging` and that no matter what happens to `PingTest.time` after that, the value of `pinging` will not change unless you update it.

If you want `pinging` to have the value of `PingTest.time` value after the pinging is done, you have to set it after the pinging is done. You can use `WaitUntil` for this, by the way:

```
IEnumerator TestPing()
{
    var PingTest = new Ping("http://localhost:8081/website/index.php");

    yield return new WaitUntil(()=>PingTest.isDone);

    pinging = PingTest.time;
    pingText.text = (PingTest.time).ToString() + " ms";
}
```

By the way, typical convention for C# is to name local variables in `camelCase` like `pingTest`.